# I couldn't understand the sentence mentioned down below, the highlighted part from the memoir of Barack Obama. Can anyone please help me?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have uploaded the image down below to make you well known about the trouble i am experiencing understanding the highlighted part down below. I really would love to hear from you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Poised on the spigot" -- a spigot is the device on the bottom of a beer-barrel, a bit like a tap (that is, "faucet") but more primitive. When you open the spigot, the goodies come gushing out. So, his hand is "poised" on the spigot, "placed in position, ready on the spigot".

"rain down like manna the largesse" -- this is a Biblical reference to the story that in the 40 years wandering in the Wilderness, the Israelites were fed by this food that God made to come down from the sky like rain, and be there on the ground to be harvested every morning. "Manna" means "What is it?" apparently. The story is in Exodus, if I remember correctly.

So Obama's relatives saw him as a divine provider for the people: poised in a position to cause to "rain down" upon the people (presumably the ones in wherever he is, Kenya, I believe) goodies that the Western world (by that he means "America") can provide.

"Poised to provide the benefits of Western Civilization like a God."